# access all indexes in NSMutbleArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

Does anybody know how to access all index's and not just a specific for a certain key

ie`[[anArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Number"]`

i want `[[anArray objectAtIndex:ALL ROWS]objectForKey:@"Number"]`

Thanks :)

Comment: You can use a for loop, right?

Comment: So you want an array of the values corresponding to key "Number"?

Comment: Shoud be fairly easy to achieve simply by using a fast enumeration loop.

Comment: thats exactly what i want Carl

Comment: @user1922242 Vladimir beat me to it, that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -valueForKey: method of NSArray:

```
NSArray* numbersArray = [anArray valueForKey:@"Number"];
```

This method returns an array containing results of -valueForKey: called on each element of array (putting NSNull object in case that result is nil).

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. Sometimes the answer stairs right at you in the face and you cant see it for looking :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use valueForKey

```
 [array valueForKey:@"key"];
```